# How to responsively layer and embed external html content (iframe) on top of an image?

Tags: mobile, iframe, embed

I would like to present desktop users with a phone image and overlay an iframe that displays an external website to fit the phone screen. Both should be responsive.

If possible, When the visitor is already on a mobile phone then they should see the the same thing that is seen on the desktop, but without the phone as a frame.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is the method that I use for responsive stacked divs.**

This will work for both methods you asked for, but I would suggest not loading a desktop version to the mobile users, for bandwidth purposes being they have no option to prevent the content to load.

It is based on percentages and from my experience, it has the best responsive results, with minimal coding. Once you replace the photo, you will need to adjust the width and height percentage values in the CSS to scale as desired.

**The Markup**

```
<div id="container">
      <div id="photo">
        <img src="https://d3nj7353mvgauu.cloudfront.net/media/categories/iphone-6-6s-6-plus-6s-plus-1.png" width="100%" height="auto">
          <div id="site">
            <iframe src="https://www.godaddy.com/" width="99%" height="99%"></iframe>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}

#photo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#site {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 43%;
  height: 76%;
  top: 11.75%;
  left: 28.25%;
  border: none;
}
```

JsFiddle [Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/Lnwmwf2k/)